# How to synchornize two machines

Tags: linux, synchronization

I have two machines that I use at different times. I would like certain changes I make to one machine (create/delete files, install/uninstall applications) to appear in the other. I currently use homeshick to manage my dot files and I can synchronize between machines through git. I also use syncthing to synchronize files. However I don't have a method to synchronize installed/uninstalled applications. I would also like certain files/applications to remain unsynchronized across the machines.

What is a reliable way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a NAS. Mount `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/lib`, `/var` from your local drive, and mount  `/etc`, `/usr`, `/opt`, `/srv`, `/home` from your NAS.  Or just go full PXE.

Comment: Syncing files is trivial. You can do that as per what @Stewart said or using tools like etckeeper, rsync or syncthing. Syncing package installs however is somewhat more difficult. Maybe use a tool like salt or ansible and be sure to sync and commit the changed config files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ansible](http://ansible.com) to do this. It is a tool to automate management of machines, and it can install/remove packages.

I have the following playbook for packages that I want to have installed on all* my machines, to be run after new install of a machine.

```
--- # Post install operating system

- hosts: most
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: "Install packages"
    package:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    with_items:
      - anki
      - binutils
      - clusterssh
      - dmidecode
      - etckeeper
      - fortune-mod
      - gcc
      - gitk
      - gpm
      - hdparm
      - htop
      - inotify-tools
      - kdiff3
      - keychain
      - kmplayer
      - libreoffice
      ...
```

---

* All machines included in the `most` group.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising I will try it out.